# Access Netsuite Internal Id Dynamically

Tags: netsuite

Searching the Netsuite documentations is like having a date with freddy krueger, not good. Wondering if anyone knows a way to access Netsuite product internal IDs dynamically? We have WSDK enabled and can populate item name, descriptions, weight, etc., but we have to manually enter the ide for every script we run on the product page we create.

```
<script src='http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/query/getitemname.nl?c=xxxxxx&n=1&id=3706'></script>

<script src='http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/app/site/query/getitemname.nl?c=xxxxxx&n=1&id=DYNAMICALLY PULL THE ID'></script>
```

c= is the Netsuite account number, the id= is the product internal id. We need this for every product script "getitemsdescr" "getitemweight" etc. Is there a way to access that internal id dynamically? Or do we need to manually enter them on all 200 plus product pages we are building?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to source this from inside the shopping cart, although I know it's possible, a dev I used to work with managed to do it.

You could alternatively use a SuiteLet to fetch the product Ids based on certain item parameters, and return as a JSON object to be used on by the page JS.